# Statement before fork() printing twice

Tags: c, fork, stdout, buffering, io-redirection

I was experimenting with `fork()` and re-direction to check whether the re-directions done in the parent apply to the child too. I wrote the following simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    freopen( "error.txt", "w+t", stdout ); // From now on, stdout = error.txt
    printf (" ERROR!  WHY DONT U UNDERSTAND?\n");
    if ( fork() == 0 ) 
    {   
        printf(" I AM CHILD\n");
        exit(0);
    }   
    else-
    {   
        printf (" EITHER I AM A PARENT OR SOMETHING GOT SCREWED\n");
    }   


    return 0;
}
```

The output ( `error.txt` ) I got is

```
ERROR!  WHY DONT U UNDERSTAND?
EITHER I AM A PARENT OR SOMETHING GOT SCREWED
ERROR!  WHY DONT U UNDERSTAND?
I AM CHILD
```

Surprisingly, `ERROR!  WHY DONT U UNDERSTAND?` is ***printing twice*** even though it appears much before the `fork()` is called and should only be printed once by the parent.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm not sure about this one, but make sure you flush io-buffers, before the fork. maybe the buffers get copied to the child.

Comment: This would make for an excellent interview question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since after `reopen` the stream is non-interactive, it's fully buffered and doesn't flush on `'\n'`. Before `fork` is called the buffer still contains the message, and after `fork` this buffered message was duplicated (because both processes got their own copies of `stdout`) and then flushed by both the parent and the child. See part 7.19.3 of C standard.

You can avoid such behavior by calling `fflush` just before `fork`.

Comment: I dint know that `\n` doesn't work as an automatic flusher after redirection. Thanks and +1

Comment: You could also use `setvbuf` to reconfigure `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of buffering. Do a `fflush` right after `printf`.

Both processes end up with the same copy of `stdio`'s internal stuff and both proceed to flush it at `exit`. You might also prevent it from happening if you call `_exit` in the child.

Comment: If I change `exit()` to `_exit()`, the child is not printing anything. ie `I AM CHILD` is missing from the output. Whats the difference between `exit()` and `_exit()` ?

Comment: @Stacker `_exit` doesn't flush stdio buffers.

Answer (score 1):

flushing the buffer will solve the problem. 
use fflush just after the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ERROR! WHY DONT U UNDERSTAND` is still buffered after forking and gets written by both processes.

If you add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

right after your first `printf()` the internal buffer is flushed and it only appears once in your file.